# How to get referenced model information in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-persistent

I have 3 Models

```
Address json
    number Text
    street Text
    pincode Text
    deriving Show
Person json
    email Text
    name Text
    telephone Text
    deriving Show
House json
    rent Int
    ownerId PersonId
    addressId AddressId
    deriving Show
```

I want to access all houses. Which I can get by doing

```
getHouseR :: Handler Value
getHouseR = do
 houses <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc HouseRent]
 return $ toJSON houses
```

But I get only reference to the other entities like `person & address`.

```
[{"rent":8000,"addressId":4,"ownerId":1,"id":3},{"rent":10000,"addressId":2,"ownerId":1,"id":1}]
```

I would like to get complete information of house, That means, resolve that `ownerId & addressId` and get that data sent which might look like,

```
[{"rent":8000,"address":{"number": "23", "street": "12/B", "pincode": "111111"},"owner":{"email": "hey@email.com", "name": "Moto", "telephone": "xxxxxxxxxx"},"id":3}]
```

Is there any way to add an information like `getForiegnData` to the query and that would fetch me all this ? Or any other solution ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite

Comment: you could try with https://github.com/bitemyapp/esqueleto to perform joins on your tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any direct way (similar to annotations) to fetch referenced model information. But there are 2 ways we can get this done.

1. Incase, if your database is SQL. You can use esqueleto https://github.com/bitemyapp/esqueleto/blob/master/README.md.
2. Write some boilerplate code and get information.

Create the `HouseResp` type, which will represent your response body including person and address information.

```
data HouseResp = HouseResp
  { rent :: Int
  , owner :: Person
  , address :: Address
  }
```

Then, modify `getHouseR` to fetch complete information for every house by using available reference id.

```
getHouseR :: Handler Value
getHouseR = do
  housesWithReference <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc HouseRent]
  houses <- sequence (Import.map getCompleteHouse housesWithReference)
  return $ toJSON houses


getCompleteHouse :: Entity House -> Handler HouseResp
getCompleteHouse house = runDB $ do
  let rent' = houseRent (entityVal house)
  person <- getJust (houseOwnerId (entityVal house))
  address' <- getJust (houseAddressId (entityVal house))
  return (HouseResp rent' person address')
```